# Taxation on LLC capital gains

Tags: united-states, trading, capital-gains-tax, limited-liability-company, private-company

If I formed an LLC with private investors and had short-term capital gains then,

1. Are the capital gains taxed on the amount excluding the dividends/profits paid to investors?
2. Will the investors have to pay short-term capital gains? or are they treated as regular dividend/interest?

Comment: Why does the order matter? Dividends paid are not deductible so the order does not affect your tax.

Comment: Okay, rephrased the question, basically, will capital gains be taxed excluding the dividends/profits paid to investors?

Comment: For Federal tax, it makes a big difference whether the LLC elects to be taxed as a corporation or not, see https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/limited-liability-company-llc (first unpaid google hit for: IRS LLC tax). For state tax it depends on the state, which you (also) didn't specify.